# Issue with automated test not being found in classpath file

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, selenium, automation

To start, let me just say that I *have* done quite a bit of research on my own in trying to resolve this issue.  I have looked over a bunch of answers here on SO and have tried many of them but, sadly, to no avail.

My current stack is Eclipse (Mars) with Maven and Selenium.  When attempting to run my automated tests, I get the following:

> > [INFO] Scanning for projects... [INFO]                                                                          [INFO]
> >     ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] Building automation 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT [INFO]
> >     ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [WARNING] The POM for org.testng:testng:jar:5.14.3 is invalid,
> >     transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug
> >     logging for more details [WARNING] The POM for
> >     org.testng:testng:jar:5.14.4 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if
> >     any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
> >     [WARNING] The POM for org.testng:testng:jar:5.14.5 is invalid,
> >     transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug
> >     logging for more details [INFO]  [INFO] ---
> >     maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ automation --- [INFO]
> >     Deleting C:\Users\bmoore\workspace\automation\target [INFO]  [INFO]
> >     --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ automation --- [INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered
> >     resources. [INFO] Copying 7 resources [INFO]  [INFO] ---
> >     maven-compiler-plugin:3.3:compile (default-compile) @ automation ---
> >     [INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module! [INFO] Compiling 253
> >     source files to C:\Users\bmoore\workspace\automation\target\classes
> >     [INFO]  [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources
> >     (default-testResources) @ automation --- [INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding
> >     to copy filtered resources. [INFO] Copying 3 resources [INFO]  [INFO]
> >     --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.3:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ automation --- [INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
> >     [INFO] Compiling 17 source files to
> >     C:\Users\bmoore\workspace\automation\target\test-classes [INFO]
> >
> > ### [INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.19:test (default-test) @ automation
>
> -------------------------------------------------------  T E S T S
>   ------------------------------------------------------- Running TestSuite
>
> Results :
>
> Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
>
> [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] BUILD FAILURE [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] Total time: 9.679 s [INFO] Finished at:
>   2016-02-02T10:26:53-07:00 [INFO] Final Memory: 23M/277M [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.19:test
>   (default-test) on project automation: Execution default-test of goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.19:test failed: There
>   was an error in the forked process [ERROR] org.testng.TestNGException:
>   [ERROR]  [ERROR] Cannot find class in classpath:
>   com..qa.automation.roles.SuperAdminCreateCouponTest [ERROR]
>   at org.testng.xml.XmlClass.loadClass(XmlClass.java:81) [ERROR] at
>   org.testng.xml.XmlClass.init(XmlClass.java:73) [ERROR] at
>   org.testng.xml.XmlClass.(XmlClass.java:59) [ERROR] at
>   org.testng.xml.TestNGContentHandler.startElement(TestNGContentHandler.java:546)
>   [ERROR] at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:509)
>   [ERROR] at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(AbstractXMLDocumentParser.java:182)
>   [ERROR] at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1344)
>   [ERROR] at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2787)
>   [ERROR] at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:606)
>   [ERROR] at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:510)
>   [ERROR] at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:848)
>   [ERROR] at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:777)
>   [ERROR] at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
>   [ERROR] at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
>   [ERROR] at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:643)
>   [ERROR] at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:327)
>   [ERROR] at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(SAXParser.java:195)
>   [ERROR] at org.testng.xml.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:38) [ERROR]
>   at org.testng.xml.SuiteXmlParser.parse(SuiteXmlParser.java:16) [ERROR]
>   at org.testng.xml.SuiteXmlParser.parse(SuiteXmlParser.java:9) [ERROR]
>   at org.testng.xml.Parser.parse(Parser.java:172) [ERROR] at
>   org.testng.TestNG.initializeSuitesAndJarFile(TestNG.java:300) [ERROR]
>   at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1021) [ERROR] at
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGExecutor.run(TestNGExecutor.java:282)
>   [ERROR] at
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGXmlTestSuite.execute(TestNGXmlTestSuite.java:83)
>   [ERROR] at
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGProvider.invoke(TestNGProvider.java:114)
>   [ERROR] at
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:286)
>   [ERROR] at
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:240)
>   [ERROR] at
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:121)
>   [ERROR] -> [Help 1] [ERROR]  [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of
>   the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch. [ERROR] Re-run Maven
>   using the -X switch to enable full debug logging. [ERROR]  [ERROR] For
>   more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read
>   the following articles: [ERROR] [Help 1]
>   http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException

That is the full trace of what happened.  The issue (as I see it) is with the following lines:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.19:test (default-test) on project automation: Execution default-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.19:test failed: There was an error in the forked process
>   [ERROR] org.testng.TestNGException:
>   [ERROR] 
>   [ERROR] Cannot find class in classpath: com..qa.automation.roles.SuperAdminCreateCouponTest

I have tried verifying the classpath entries, and that the surefire plugin is present.  In both cases, they are where they should be.  I have tried committing files one-at-a-time and that works.  It's only when I build that I have an issue, and it is blocking me from running the automation completely.

I am guessing that the issue is likely an easy one to resolve but, the Java/Eclipse stack is not second nature to me like .NET/C# is.

**NOTE:**  I will update the question with new information should it become available.

**UPDATE:**  I have included the POM below:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
    http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"    
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.kryterion.qa</groupId>
    <artifactId>automation</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>automation</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
       <properties>
          <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
          <skipTests>false</skipTests>
       </properties>
 <dependencies>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
       <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
       <version>6.9.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>log4j</groupId>
       <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
       <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
       <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
       <version>2.48.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
       <artifactId>selenium-firefox-driver</artifactId>
       <version>2.48.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
       <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
       <version>2.48.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
       <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
       <version>2.48.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>mysql</groupId>
       <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
       <version>5.1.37</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>com.google.inject</groupId>
       <artifactId>guice</artifactId>
       <version>3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>net.sourceforge.jexcelapi</groupId>
       <artifactId>jxl</artifactId>
       <version>2.6.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
       <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
       <version>3.10-FINAL</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.uncommons</groupId>
       <artifactId>reportng</artifactId>
       <version>1.1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
       <artifactId>velocity</artifactId>
       <version>1.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
       <artifactId>derby</artifactId>
       <version>10.11.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
       <artifactId>mybatis</artifactId>
       <version>3.2.8</version>
    </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
       <finalName>automation</finalName>
    <plugins>
       <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.3</version>
          <configuration>
             <source>1.8</source>
             <target>1.8</target>
             <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
          </configuration>
       </plugin>
       <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.19</version>
          <configuration>
             <skipTests>${skipTests}</skipTests>
             <systemPropertyVariables>
                <environment>${envName}</environment>
             </systemPropertyVariables>
             <suiteXmlFiles>
                <suiteXmlFile>src/test/resources/testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
             </suiteXmlFiles>
         </configuration>
       </plugin>
    </plugins>
 </build>
<reporting>
   <plugins>
   <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.16</version>
   </plugin>
   <plugin>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
      <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.7</version>
   </plugin>
   <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-changelog-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.2</version>
         <configuration>
            <issueLinkUrl>http://prodjira01:8080/browse/%ISSUE%</issueLinkUrl>
         </configuration>
   </plugin>
   <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.9.1</version>
   <configuration>
      <show>private</show>
      <additionalparam>${javadoc.doclint.none}</additionalparam>
   </configuration>
   </plugin>
   <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-jxr-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.3</version>
   </plugin>
   <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.4</version>
   <configuration>
      <linkXRef>true</linkXRef>
      <source>1.8</source>
      <targetJdk>1.8</targetJdk>
   <rulesets>
      <ruleset>/rulesets/java/basic.xml</ruleset>
      <ruleset>/rulesets/java/braces.xml</ruleset>
      <ruleset>/rulesets/java/design.xml</ruleset>
   </rulesets>
</configuration>
   </plugin>
   <plugin>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
      <artifactId>taglist-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.4</version>
<configuration>
   <tagListOptions>
   <tagClasses>
   <tagClass>
      <displayName>Todo</displayName>
   <tags>
   <tag>
      <matchString>todo</matchString>
      <matchType>ignoreCase</matchType>
   </tag>
   <tag>
      <matchString>FIXME</matchString>
      <matchType>ignoreCase</matchType>
   </tag>
   <tag>
      <matchString>NB</matchString>
      <matchType>exact</matchType>
   </tag>
   </tags>
</tagClass>
<tagClass>
   <displayName>Deprecated</displayName>
   <tags>
   <tag>
      <matchString>@deprecated</matchString>
      <matchType>ignoreCase</matchType>
   </tag>
</tags>
</tagClass>
</tagClasses>
</tagListOptions>
</configuration>
</plugin>
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
   <artifactId>findbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>3.0.0</version>
<configuration>
   <xmlOutput>true</xmlOutput>
   <!-- Optional directory to put findbugs xdoc xml report -->
   <xmlOutputDirectory>target/site</xmlOutputDirectory>
</configuration>
</plugin>
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
<configuration>
<configLocation>config/sun_checks.xml</configLocation>
</configuration>
</plugin>
</plugins>
</reporting>
</project>
```

**@sircapsalot** - I made the change you suggested below and what happened is that all of the:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;
```

Suddenly started throwing warnings in *all the classes* that had those imports.  Thoughts?

Comment: I'm not familiar with TestNG but there are two dots after the "com" in the package name part of the class that cannot be found in classpath. Maybe you have defined wrong package name in some configuration file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Maven Central](https://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.testng%22%20AND%20a%3A%22testng%22), the version you are requesting isn't there. *(you are requesting org.testng:testng:jar:**5.14.3**)*

Try updating to the newest version: `6.9.10` in your pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
    <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
    <version>6.9.10</version>
</dependency>
```

[image: maven central search]

Comment: Hey man, thanks for the answer.  It wasn't 100% spot-on, BUT, it did get my mind working in another direction that helped me resolve the issue.  I marked this as an answer regardless because it will help someone else too.

Comment: excellent :) glad to hear.  sometimes that's all it takes!  just another way to look at something.

Answer (score 0):

So, I figured out the issue... It turns out, it was a problem with [PEBKAC](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=pebkac).

I renamed a file that I had changed yesterday back to its original state and all is well now.  Thanks for those that chimed in to help with this!